# Investigate unsafe certificate warning on a major site

Tags: security, ssl, certificate, ssl-certificate, tls1.2

Ok, so I want your opinion on this...

I have this brand new Windows Server 2012 R2 with all the latest updates.
When I use IE or Chrome and visits www.flashback.org, I get warnings about certificate errors.

Please look at what Chrome is telling me:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Seexd.png

Now, I raised the issue on the flashback forums. Everyone just said the problem in on my end.

So...
where exactly lies the problem? On the server, or on my client?

(I don't want to add exception and just ignore the security problem)

Please don't answer unless you have a pretty good idea what the problem is.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is on your side (client). Du to some unknown reasons GoDaddy root certificate (Go Daddy Class 2 Certification Authority) is not installed on your machine's Trusted Root CAs container.

By default, Windows trusts this CA. It is listed in the active [authrootstl.cab](http://www.download.windowsupdate.com/msdownload/update/v3/static/trustedr/en/authrootstl.cab) file.

This may indicate that someone deleted this certificate from certificate store.

Comment: ok thanks, but how exactly do I solve this problem? And why isn't it fixed on some update in Windows?

Comment: you need to re-import this CA certificate to the `Local Macine\Trusted Root CAs` container.